# deleting all occurrences of a character before the next different character

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a postgres table I have a column with values like:

```
code
=============
000A450
00BVDDE
0FGR0SE
GVSDD33
```

I need to delete all 0 before the next character that is NOT a 0. So, the previous column will became:

```
new Code
=============
A450
BVDDE
FGR0SE
GVSDD33
```

Is this possible in psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ltrim('00BVDDE', '0');

 ltrim 
═══════
 BVDDE
(1 row)
```

(No comment necessary.)